# How to make outbound call from the phone? Twilio

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, react-native, twilio

My case is next:
I have an app where I receive all calls recordings from Twilio, and do some operations using AI and other tools on it.
I also need to handle outbound calls, for now only inbound are present in Twilio, because outbound calls are done directly without Twilio as intermediary.

So, I have created the React Native mobile app, where I expect to type a phone number of some person and call to her, and I want to receive recording of that call in Twilo. How can I solve it?

Flow is next:

- Me, PhoneNumber1
- Person, PhoneNumber2,
- Twilio, PhoneNumber3 (purchased number)

Expected flow:
I send request to API from mobile app with from=PhoneNumber1, to=PhoneNumber3 and using Twilio I connect that two phones, I think it's similar to conversations, but I am not sure that it's the most effective solution.

What do you think can help solve me that?

Possible solution but looking for other if they do exist:

```
client.calls.create({
  from: 'verified caller id',
  to: 'my personal number',
  record: true,
  twiml: `
  <Response>
  <Say>Test</Say>
  <Dial>person's number</Dial>
  </Response>`
});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide some code.

Comment: Does your code not work as expected? The alternative is to use a Conference Add Participant resource.

Comment: @jassent Okay, how then with incoming calls, how to process them between the caller, my personal phone and Twilio?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio makes available this tutorial - ["How to Respond to Incoming Phone Calls"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-respond-to-incoming-phone-calls/node).

You can use either your own server, [Twilio Serverless Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless), or [Twilio Studio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio) to receive a call and forward to your personal phone number.

Comment: My Personal Number - PN
My Callee Number - CN
Twilio Number - TN

CN needs to be able to send directly to PN, he doesn't need to know anything about TN.

Comment: But I think then, that PN needs to be provided by Twilio to provide all recordings/sms messages

Comment: Twilio can only process phone numbers owned by Twilio. You can purchase a new number from Twilio, give that phone number to your customers, then have Twilio forward the calls to your cellphone. Or, you can "port" your cellphone number to Twilio and get a new phone number from your cellphone provider for your cellphone. I think the more common scenario is to buy a new number from Twilio. The cost to buy a number from Twilio is minimal.